# Using switch to compare against an array of values

Tags: arrays, switch-statement, swift2

I have created a Swift 2 function that takes an input string and converts it to title case, without converting small words that are normally kept lowercase in titles. The code is here:

```
/*
Function: toTitleCase
Intent:   Take in String type and convert it to title case
*/
func toTitleCase(var inputString: String) -> String {

    // Convert entire input string to lower case first
    inputString = inputString.lowercaseString

    // A place holder for the string as it is being built
    var workString = ""

    // Set boolean to always convert the first word
    var isFirstWord = true

    // Get list of words from inputString
    let words = inputString.characters.split{$0 == " "}.map(String.init)

    for eachWord in words {
        switch eachWord {
            // If the word is in the list, do not convert it
            case "a","an","by","in","of","on","the","is","for","from":
                if isFirstWord {
                    fallthrough // If it is the first word, allow conversion
                } else {
                    workString = workString + " " + eachWord
                }
                // For any other word, convert it
            default:
                workString = workString + " " + eachWord.capitalizedString
        }
        isFirstWord = false
    }
    return workString
}
```

In the case statement, the values are hard coded, which in this situation is probably not the best idea. Since I will likely need to add more words to this list in the future, a more ideal approach would be to read the list of excluded words from a plist file into an array and have a case like this:

```
case [excludedWords]:
     (code to skip conversion)
```

Obviously this will not work since you cannot compare a String type to an Array type. Is there another way to easily implement this using case, or will I need to scrap it and use something like a for-in loop?

Has anyone else developed code to implement this logic, and can you help me to find a more elegant and efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `contains` on the array of excluded words by using `case let ... where` like this:

```
func toTitleCase(var inputString: String) -> String {

    // Convert entire input string to lower case first
    inputString = inputString.lowercaseString

    // A place holder for the string as it is being built
    var workString = ""

    // Set boolean to always convert the first word
    var isFirstWord = true

    // Get list of words from inputString
    let words = inputString.characters.split{$0 == " "}.map(String.init)

    let excludedWords = ["a","an","by","in","of","on","the","is","for","from"]

    for eachWord in words {
        switch eachWord {
            // If the word is in the list, do not convert it
        case let word where excludedWords.contains(word):
            if isFirstWord {
                fallthrough // If it is the first word, allow conversion
            } else {
                workString = workString + " " + eachWord
            }
            // For any other word, convert it
        default:
            workString = workString + " " + eachWord.capitalizedString
        }
        isFirstWord = false
    }
    return workString
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is truly an elegant solution! Many thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one with persistent memory support

```
var excludedWords:[String] = ["a","an","by","in","of","on","the","is","for","from"]

//store and retrive stack
typealias plist = AnyObject
var consistentExcludeList:plist?{ //guarenteed to be string 
get{
    return excludedWords
}
set{
    if let excludedWordsArray = newValue as? [String]{
        for element in excludedWordsArray{
            excludedWords.append(element)
        }
    }
}
}
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
func saveStack(){
    defaults.setObject(consistentExcludeList, forKey: "consistentExcludeList")
}
func retrieveStack(){
    consistentExcludeList = defaults.objectForKey("consistentExcludeList")
}

//to titlecase
func toTitleCase(inputString: String) -> String {
    var workString = ""
    let array = workString.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
    for word in array{
        if excludedWords.contains(word){
            word.capitalizedString
        }
        workString += word
    }
    return workString
}
```